# SEHException while in paint() - .NET handling is ruining call stack

Tags: c++, exception, stack-trace, callstack, crash-dumps

I have error handling code that is designed to catch unnhandled exceptions, and then create a dump.

Now, i've encountered a few situations where this doesn't work well in the transition between Native and managed code.

For example if in a `Paint()` event I call some native code, and that native code throws an exception.
The message loop dispatcher will catch the native exception, and then rethrow a .NET `SEHException`.
Same thing happens sometimes with DLLS that host COM objects.

The problem with this is that because of the stack-roll back and the way it catches and creates an `SEHException` from the native exception, the actual Native call stack is destroyed.

Can i get the native call stack somehow, using the `SEHException` ? (note that the call stack in the SEHException is the CLR call stack).

Or can i set the application so it will save the call stack somehow ?

Comment: Does this help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/01/30/363428.aspx or this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/01/18/355697.aspx

Comment: @EdChum - Nope, those methods (the 1003f trick) work only on x86. I happen to work with an x64 program. But it is a good advice for anyone working with x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that **.Net** called `Paint()` when it needed to paint a window.
Apparently **.Net** made this very safe and added extra precautions and error handling.

Now my `Paint()` event called a **C++/CLI** wrapper dll that called a native **C++** dll. The native **C++** exception raised an **Access Violation** exception.

Now the **.Net** caught that exception, and wrapped it up as a managed `SEHException` object, and I've lost all the call stack from the actual error point.

***Solution:***

We need to catch the exception before the **.Net** exception handling.
The usual exception handling flow can be found on the net, but this sites gives a good example of the actual flow: **[Exception handlers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhanli/archive/2010/06/25/c-tips-addvectoredexceptionhandler-addvectoredcontinuehandler-and-setunhandledexceptionfilter.aspx)**

It seems that the .Net catches the exceptions and wraps them before the **SetUnhandledExceptionFilter** handler is called.

So, I've added a first chance exception handler with **`AddVectoredExceptionHandler`** and checked for fatal exceptions by checking the errorcode.

```
//SEH exceptions have code 0xC0000xxxx
#define SEH_TYPE (DWORD)0xC0000000L 
//mask the last byte
#define SEH_MASK (DWORD)0xFF000000L 
    LONG WINAPI CheckForSEHException( struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *lpTopLevelExceptionFilter)
    {   
        if ((lpTopLevelExceptionFilter->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode & SEH_MASK) == SEH_TYPE) //mask and check the last bits if it's an SEH exception
        {
            //handle exception here (create a dump or something)
            return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
        }
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }
```

The exception codes can be found in **WinBase.h**, you can follow the definitions to the actual error codes. (ie. look for `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`)

Answer (score 1):

Try !dumpheap -type SEHException . Use the address of SEHException to print !pe ***address of exception*** . You will get the callstack

Comment: I have the call stack of the SEHException. the problem is that the managed exception only contains the managed callstack. So i dont have the native callstack.